# Links work in Angular Application but not Address Bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I type website.com/about-us/ in the address bar it breaks.

- Says "Not Found" instead of loading the page

If I type website.com/#!/about-us in the address bar, it goes to the right page. // Added hashbang or #!

If I click a link on the page to website.com/about-us/ (without the hashbang), it works. How do I fix it so I can just go to the website without a hash bang from the address bar?

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

## Update

Here's my server config

```
app.route('/').get(index.render); // UPDATE: This is why the home page was loading and I could click links

app.get('/.\*', function (req, res, next) {

    if(req.url.substring(0,4) === "/api") {
      return next();
    } else {
    res.send(index.render) // render is a function in the index controller

    }

});
```

Comment: You haven't shown or mentioned which server you are using, but this has all the signatures of a server that isn't configured properly for html5Mode.  See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my question with my express configuration

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR: link clicks work as expected because your JavaScript has already loaded

Since your using a UI router, link clicks are "told" by Angular to go to the appropriate hashbang route unless you use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`, which you are. So in this case, link clicks know to use `html5Mode` because *the JavaScript in your page has already loaded*.

When you enter the link in the address bar manually, the JavaScript hasn't had a chance to load, so it doesn't "know" to map the appropriate non-hashbang route to the correct view in your app.

To get the desired behavior, you'll need to configure your server to route correctly:

```
app.get('/some-page', doStuff);
```

Comment: Thanks Josh! Does this mean I need an express route for all my angular app pages? Until this point I was using $stateProvider

Comment: @Zeus, no prob! If you want to be able to navigate directly through the URL bar to a non-hashbanged route, then yes, you'll need express routes for all of them. Why do you not want to use the `#!`? That's actually a pretty elegant way to do it.

Comment: Good question, Josh. I ran a fresh git push to the heroku server and the npm install updated all my dependencies. There's a question mark in my urls now after the hash bang and I was just trying to get everything up to speed again.

Comment: @Zeus, lol I'm lost now (must be confusing myself...). So was your issue resolved then?